# Git source control :: About safely remove USB hard disk after I created a source repository?

Tags: git, usb, tortoisegit

I want to sync my project source between the computer in my workplace and the computer at home. So I don't have to copy all the source file just because I changed one file or two.

So I use Git. My computer's OS is Windows XP.
i have installed 
Git-1.7.4-preview20110204.exe
TortoiseGit-1.6.5.0-32bit.msi.

I created a source repository in my USB hard disk, and my work dir is in my computer hard disk. seems goes well. 
but when i want to safely remove the USB hard disk, windows warns me the USB disk is in used,can't be removed. i end the process "TGitCache.exe", problem is still there.

how can i remove the USB hard disk safely with my Git source repository in there???

Thank you very very... much!

Answer (score 2):

It is a problem with TortioseGit, not with git itself. Go to TortoiseGit settings -> Icon overlays and exclude your USB stick from paths.

This process actively watches your filesystem to detect where to put which overlay icons. The most complicated task is when you changes some deeply nested file and want to see 'changed' icon on every folder - from root to the most nested one.

There's also many complaints that this process could use many resources like CPU power or access disk actively. Thus I'm always turning it off at all by setting Status cache = None option. Thus I'm effectively loosing these icons usefulness, but I'm using console anyway, so it is not much for me.